# Strange getUserMedia issue?

Tags: webrtc

I'm working on an html application that uses getUserMedia. It works great so far but there is one little problem:

The web application is also being called from local file system. That means file://.

Ok, WebRTC is unavailable in this case. When the Browser tries to call

navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function(localMediaStream) {...}, function(error) {alert("blabla webrtc unavailable";)});

it should run into an error and call the error callback.

In case of file://, none of these two callbacks will be ever called.

In another case, the web application is running over regular http://, a warning is given, that the WebRTC feature is unavailable in insecure environments, but here the error callback is working as expected.

I need the error callback to tell the user, that WebRTC is unavailable.

What is wrong here?

(It is used for an unimportant feature. And only getUserMedia() is used, not the entire WebRTC-Workflow. But it is ugly, if it run into a blank screen)

And no, there is no waiting popup which ask the user for permission :-)

The problem is Chrome only. Probably a Browser bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Silently failing for file:// is documented Chrome behaviour, see [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/). If you can control Chrome, the [allow-file-access-from-files](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) flag enables getUserMedia from file urls.

Comment: Oh no... What bad behavior. It must run under default chrome setup. Any workaround for that? :-D

Comment: @user2766477 What about just checking if window.location.href starts with "file://" and showing the error before even trying to call getUserMedia?

Comment: X.x damn easy solution! So easy that I didn't had that idea by myself. Such a switch already exists in that app. Thank you!!